# WiFi unable to turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, wifi, airport

WiFi is unable to turn on and connect to network. I have tried many options available on the Internet and nothing is working to allow my MacBook Pro to connect to a WiFi network.

When in System Report under the WiFi tab it states *Airport Utility: Not Installed* (as shown in attached picture).

When I try to delete the network and reinstall it the WiFi option is not available in interface/service name (as shown in pic.)

I attempted to reset NVRAM & SMC - this turned WiFi on for a few seconds allowed me to connect then it dropped again and I was not able to turn WiFi back on; so back to square one.

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Running macOS Catalina - model A1278

[image: WiFi image 1]

[image: WiFi image 2]

Comment: No pics are visible. Use the "Edit" button below your question text, then select the little mountain-and-moon/sun icon to attach the pics. Please also tell us the model of your Mac, and version of macOS its running.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for that. I have now updated and added photos

Comment: Hi Amelia!  I edited the post and adjusted the images to make it easier to read.  Even though it is a dupe, it's a good question (so +1 from me) to provide another avenue to the existing solution.  Also, in the future, you don't need to use your camera to get an image of what's on your screen.  See Apple Support Document [How to Take a Screenshot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361)  - this will help you out tremendously!